# Submit a new binary after app status "Developer Removed From Sale"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-app

It looks there is no way to submit new build for review after an app is removed from sale by the developer.

We wanted to do some test on how it looks in the actual app store. So, we released the app for few hours and removed it.

Now when we try to submit a new binary we are not able to remove the old one as we usually do as shown on the below screenshot. The Red button was supposed to show up when you hover over the old build.

[image]

Comment: upload a new version/build and it should be fine. you can't upload the same one.

Comment: You have to create a new version

Comment: That would be the last option, was wondering if I can keep the current version.

Comment: no, which is why we said you **have** to create a new version. Once a version has been 'Ready for sale' that version has been released, you cannot issue a new release with the same version number.

Answer (score 4):

To make your app available open it in **App Store Connect**, then select **App Store** **->** **Pricing and Availability**, and then switch **Availability** from **Remove from sale** to **All territories selected** as shown below.

[image: Pricing and Availability]